# How to check if dictionary contain an entry/ies and use as a condition for an if loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm having trouble finding a way to find if a dictionary is empty or not and how to use it for a condition for an if loop,
this is my current if loop:

```
if del_question == "2":
```

I'm trying to make it so that there is an additional condition so that you cannot enter the if loop if the dictionary is empty.

this is my dictionary at the start:
`dictionary = {}`

The user can input and remove key and value pairings and can also delete them, this if condition is what allows the user to delete their pairings but I don't want it so that they can get stuck on the while loop inside if they do not have any pairings.

Full loop for those who are interested:

```
if del_question == "2":
    print('These are you letter and symbol pairings', dictionary)
    del_letter = input("Please input the symbol you wish to unpair: ")
    while len(del_letter) != 1:
        print(del_letter, 'is not a valid input please try again or type "end" if you do not want to change a pairing')
        del_letter = input("Please input the symbol you wish to unpair: ")
    del_symbol = dict.get(dictionary, del_letter)
    words = words.replace(del_symbol, del_letter)
    del dictionary[del_letter]
    print(words)
```

Comment: Note: `if` statements aren't loops. An `if` will never cause its body to be executed repeatedly; some other control flow construct such as `for` or `while` around the `if` would do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if dictionary:
```

Anything with a nonzero `len` is considered true as a boolean value, and anything with a zero `len` is considered false (except in the case where the object has a `__bool__` method that uses a different rule).